# Method to monitor home electricity supply interruptions

Tags: power-on

I am looking for a way to find out, in a day at what timings electricity supply was interrupted. I guess if we keep our android device on charging all day we should be able to find power interruption by just knowing the current charging status of the device. So is there any app or method which can help ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Battery history:** https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.psw.batteryToast&hl=en

This app may help, you can access the ‘unplugged/plugged log’ through the ‘charging’ button, which is on the top left of the app interface. It should be able to tell you when its ‘unplugged’ when it stops charging.

It’s ad and purchase free, but the downside is that the interface seems to be quite confusing and messy.
The below image is one of the app’s image preview on the play store.
[image: image of log from the app store preview]